# Azure B2C - Custom Policy - Custom UI - Change Password _ continue button disable

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have followed this tutorial 'https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset'. Everything worked well. However when I try to add custom UI page to style whole change password wizard, 'continue' button disabled after email verified. Also I couldn't find a way to remove change email button in change password workflow.

Only change that I made was adding custom page to style change password pages.

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
   <LoadUri>https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/yyy/selfasserted.html</LoadUri>
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item>
   </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

Custom html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Remove the provided password reset link
            $("#forgotPassword").remove();

            // Move the new password reset button to the right position
            $("#PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange").detach().appendTo("label[for='password']");

            // Set the style of the password reset button to look like a link
            $("#PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange").attr("style",
                "background: none!important; color:#2872DD; border:none;  padding:0!important; font-size: .75em;  height: auto; width: auto;  margin-left: 5px");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a specific error message being thrown?

Comment: Might be some conflicting JavaScript or css in your html file.

Comment: @Nelles No JS errors

Comment: I think I noticed one time that ready() doesn't tell you the UI content is loaded, since it adds the UI components after loading your HTML. So you might need to do some form of wait for the content to actually be there.

Comment: Hi @Amal Note that Azure AD B2C references a specific version of jQuery. [You mustn't include a different version of it](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#guidelines-for-using-javascript). Otherwise this causes issues.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett removing extra jquery link from custom UI page worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @Amal I am having a similar requirement and the issue is that the javascript code in the html template for password reset is not working when uploaded on the cloud. 
I have a separate html template file for password reset.
I have the javascript execution enabled per documentation in the replying part which is SignUpSignIn.xml policy for me
 <UserJourneyBehaviors>
     <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
 </UserJourneyBehaviors>
Any thoughts on this? Am I doing anything wrong? Did you have a separate html file password reset? How did you get the jQuery running? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Azure AD B2C guidelines for use of JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#guidelines-for-using-javascript) indicate you must include a different version of jQuery; otherwise, this causes issues in the page UI.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your jQuery script tag. Azure B2C uses a specific version of jQuery. Adding another version of jQuery can cause errors. You can still jQuery in your code, but you do not need to include the script tag for jQuery since it already loads via the azure API. To change the version of jQuery, you can update the DataUri in your policy. [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout)